# TypeScript: Type 'RedisClientType<...' is not assignable to type 'RedisClient | Redis | Cluster | undefined'

Tags: typescript, redis, connect-redis

I'm trying to use connect-redis and express-session for session management and I'm getting an error when passing in my Redis client.

Here is the code:

```
const app = express();

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
let redisClient = redis.createClient({ legacyMode: true });
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);

app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({
      client: redisClient,
      disableTouch: true,
    }),
    cookie: {
    maxAge: 10000000000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
  })
)
```

I'm following the guide posted [here](https://dev.to/lastnameswayne/how-to-implement-authentication-with-graphql-and-redis-1k1b). Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I had `@types/connect-redis^0.0.19` as a dev dependency. I removed it and added `@types/connect-redis@0.0.14` which solved my issue. `connect-redis` is version `5.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

You probably imported types from the package `@types/redis`. Looking at its Yarn page, we see that `@types/redis` is now deprecated with this note:

> redis provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/redis installed!

The latest version of the package is `4.0.11`, released on Dec 9, 2021. I'm guessing the error arises from the differences between this package and newer versions of the package `redis`.

To remove the package `@types/redis`, you can run `$ yarn remove @types/redis`.

I had a similar error and that stopped VS Code from complaining.